# Checksum serial message

Tags: python, hardware

I must calculated a checksum, but i'm very news on hardware programing...

the doc say :

- All the serial command are 12-byte command packet format
- The values of the first 11 bytes of the packet (excluding the checksum byte) are summed and then divided by 0x0100 (256). This will create a 1-byte shift. The remaining value from this shift is the checksum byte.
- during word transmission the high word value is transmitted followed by the low word value

example of command :

0x00    0x05    0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x00    Chksum

- 0x00 : channel
- 0x05 : command
- 0x0000 : param1
- 0x0000 : param2
- 0x0000 : lwExtraData
- 0x0000 : hwExtraData
- 0x00 : ErrorCode
- ????? : check sum

i have this code in python :

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200,parity='N',timeout=1)
ser.open()

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # channel 1 byte (alway the same)
ser.write(chr(0x05)) # command 1 byte

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # param1 2 bytes (byte low)
ser.write(chr(0x00)) # param1 2 bytes (byte hight)

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # param2 2 bytes (byte low)
ser.write(chr(0x00)) # param2 2 bytes (byte hight)

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # lwExtraData 2 bytes (byte low)
ser.write(chr(0x00)) # lwExtraData 2 bytes (byte hight)

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # hwExtraData 2 bytes (byte low)
ser.write(chr(0x00)) # hwExtraData 2 bytes (byte hight)

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # ErrorCode 1 byte
```

How i can calculated my checksum ?? if i sum i have 5 but how i can divide ?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by `0x100` (Use `//` instead of `/` to prevent true division which yields float value)

```
checksum = sum_of_11_bytes // 0x100
```

or shift 1 byte (8bit)

```
checksum = sum_of_11_bytes >> 8
```